# How do I set the topic from the command line when I push a new commit to gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

When uploading a git commit for code review on Gerrit (2.8), I would like to be able to set the topic field (e.g. g-tune-pme-reform here https://gerrit.gromacs.org/#/c/3453/3). How can this be done from the command line? Can it be done in the original git push?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

yes, it is possible using the push command:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master/<topic_name>
```

Comment: You have to use a new syntax in newer Gerrit versions: `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master%topic=<topic_name>`

Comment: Is it possible to make topic required? E.g. reject push without topic

Comment: @OlegOleg ask this in a separate question

Comment: What if I don't want to amend the patchset but **ONLY** to rename a topic? Currently I have the error: `commit already exists as current patchset` ?

Comment: @bloody - i think you should create a new question for this

Comment: I could create a question if you knew the solution. You didn't assure this so I deduce you do not.

Comment: @bloody yes, but someone else might know, just use the tag gerrit

Comment: Gerrit documentation: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-user.html#topics